# How to read Linear Program from an optimal tableau

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex, operations-research

Suppose we are given an optimal tableau and the objective function. How can we determine the RHS of constraints or if possible the constraint equations?

For example consider the given tableau with objective to maximize $z = 5x_1 + 6x_2 + 8x_3$

[Example tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0XJ1.png)

We can tell that there are two sets of constraints. How can we determine the RHS of each constraint say $A$ and $B$?

Comment: you mean the initial RHS of A and B?

Comment: @kuifje Yes, the initial RHS constraints, or in other words the initial dual coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *impossible* to determine the initial RHS of each constraint without the initial LHS.  Given two initial constraints $\eqref{A}$ and $\eqref{B}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j} x_j &= b_1 \tag{A} \label{A} \\
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{2j} x_j &= b_2 \tag{B} \label{B}
\end{align}

If none of these two equations is redundant (which is true in this case since the basic solution in the given optimal tableau is not degenerate), you can change one constraint by adding another to it.  This will give you a *different* initial RHS.

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j} x_j &= b_1 \tag{A'} \label{A'} \\
\sum_{j=1}^n (a_{1j} + a_{2j}) x_j &= b_1 + b_2 \tag{B'} \label{B'}
\end{align}

Comment: I would definitely agree with you for the general case. But given the specific optimal tableau, suppose row operations were performed to return the coefficient row to the original objective function. Would it then recover the two constraints exactly as it is in rows 2 and 3 which led to this specific tableau? Or would there still exist multiple possible constraints?

Comment: @cppgnlearner Sorry for my delayed response.  I've just come back.  The later is true.  You can add row 2 to row 3 many times, so it's impossible to get the constraint with *exactly* the same coefficients $a_{ij}$'s, but you'll get two *equivalent* conditions which give you the *same* feasible region.  I think this is good enough for practical purposes.